# Create Custom UIView From Subclass On Main Thread iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uiview

I have the following code to a run method that returns a `UIImage` made from a `UIView` that's created in separate `UIView` class file. The `FlagMarkerView` is a separate subclass of `UIView` and is referenced here. The problem is the line `FlagMarker *markerView...` throws the following Main Thread Checker Error and crashes the app.

> UIView.init(coder:) must be used from the main thread.

The code used to work as is, but no longer works as I've updated the project to target iOS 11.

I tried wrapping the `FlagMarkerView` call in a `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{});` but that doesn't work because it doesn't get picked up by the return `UIImage` in the method. I also tried to use a `-(void)` method instead of returning a `UIImage`, but that’s hazard with the complexity of my project.

Is there a way I can create the `newMarkerImage` in `- (void)updateMyFlagsWitAlert:` and use `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{` for `FlagMarkerView` so `newMarkerImage` can be created in line from `markerImage`.

```
- (void)updateMyFlagsWitAlert:(BOOL)isAllowed{
    for (AGSGraphic *graphic in weakSelf.flagOverlay.graphics) {
        FlagModel *flagToUpdate = graphic.attributes[@"flag"];
           UIImage *newMarkerImage =
                    [weakSelf markerImageForFlag:flagToUpdate withDetail:detail];
    }
}


- (UIImage *)markerImageForFlag:(FlagModel *)flag withDetail:(BOOL)withDetail {

    // This line crashes app
    FlagMarkerView *markerView = [[[NSBundle mainBundle]  loadNibNamed:@"FlagMarkerView" owner:self options:nil] objectAtIndex:0];

    [markerView setFlag:flag];
    UIImage *markerImage = [markerView imageWithDetail:withDetail];
    [markerView layoutIfNeeded];
    return markerImage;
}
```

[image]

Comment: This is a little strange to load a NIB for a view that you’ll render to an image and then discard the view. It would be interesting to know what `FlagMarkerView` is doing, because it’s likely that one might be able to simplify this dramatically, getting the view out of this process altogether, allowing you to generate this image from a background thread.

Answer (score 2):

You should probably redesign your code to be async, but the quickest way I could think of is something like:

```
    __block FlagMarkerView *markerView;
    dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        markerView = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"FlagMarkerView" owner:self options:nil] objectAtIndex:0];
        [markerView setFlag:flag];
        UIImage *markerImage = [markerView imageWithDetail:withDetail];
        [markerView layoutIfNeeded];
    });
    return markerImage;
```

This will make your code run in the main thread, and wait for it to finish.
It is not a good design, you should probably design your code better and not rely on a return value.
Instead, your code could use a block as a parameter that will receive the result after it was processed in the main thread, instead of waiting for it using a semaphore.
But sometimes, if you just need something to work - this solution could be helpful.

Comment: @Rob, it would, I just scribbled fast without thinking :-) will change it.

Comment: @Rob - I did write about changing the design to a completion handler or the sorts, but it's not really possible to provide a better answer without the rest of the code.

Comment: Thanks for making a suggestion. This answer produces a UIImage for markerImage from   markerView within the dispatch block, but the return MarkerImage does not make it back to the call to markerImageForFlag. Any other suggestions? Or what other code would be helpful?

Comment: @user2621075 Did you use `dispatch_sync` like Moshe suggested? Or did you accidentally use `dispatch_async`?

Comment: @Rob - good catch! That makes all the difference. I posted the answer.

Answer (score 0):

The following code-change solved my problem. I found the problem is not with `markerImageForFlag` at all even though the Main Thread Checker highlighted the `markerView`. I believe the `weakSelf` reference put the task on the background thread, which was ok for awhile, but doesn't work anymore. All I had to do is put the `dispatch_sync`, not `dispatch_async`, on the call, `newMarkerImage`. Thanks to @Rob and @Moshe! See below.

```
- (void)updateMyFlagsWitAlert:(BOOL)isAllowed{
    for (AGSGraphic *graphic in weakSelf.flagOverlay.graphics) {
        FlagModel *flagToUpdate = graphic.attributes[@"flag"];

        __block UIImage *newMarkerImage = nil;

        dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{        
        newMarkerImage = [weakSelf markerImageForFlag:flagToUpdate withDetail:(scale < markerThreshold)];
        });

    }
```

}